# Submitting form within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Probably a very easy fix for you JS gurus out there, currently I have a form with some basic validation. If i call it outside of a submit function it works fine, however i need the form to submit once it checks the validation, can anyone help? Also is the correct way to call it by returning true at the bottom of the function?

```js
function submitForm() {
  //Form validation, post.
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Form fields
    const contactName = document.getElementById("form__contact-name").value;
    const contactEmail = document.getElementById("form__contact-email").value;
    const contactPhone = document.getElementById("form__contact-phone").value;
    const contactMessage = document.getElementById("form__contact-message").value;

    //Check if values aren't empty, if they're not post form. Else alert the user to complete.
    contactName !== '' && contactEmail !== '' && contactPhone !== '' && contactMessage !== '' ?
      true :
      alert("Please complete form");
  })
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your name">Your Name</label>
    <input id="form__contact-name" type="text" name="contact-name" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your email">Your email address</label>
    <input id="form__contact-email" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your phone number">Your phone number</label>
    <input id="form__contact-phone" type="number" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your message">Your message</label>
    <textarea id="form__contact-message" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="send my message" onsubmit="submitForm()" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preventDefault() only if the validation doesn't pass.

```js
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  const contactName = document.getElementById("form__contact-name").value;
  const contactEmail = document.getElementById("form__contact-email").value;
  const contactPhone = document.getElementById("form__contact-phone").value;
  const contactMessage = document.getElementById("form__contact-message").value;

  if (contactName === '' || contactEmail === '' || contactPhone === '' || contactMessage === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please complete form");
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="contact-form">

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your name">Your Name</label>
    <input id="form__contact-name" type="text" name="contact-name" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your email">Your email address</label>
    <input id="form__contact-email" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your phone number">Your phone number</label>
    <input id="form__contact-phone" type="number" />
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <label for="Your message">Your message</label>
    <textarea id="form__contact-message" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form__contact-wrapper">
    <input type="submit" value="send my message" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My validation still doesn't fire?

Comment: If you run the above code snippet, leave a field empty and submit the form, validation will prevent the post request.

Comment: Hmmm, when i copy and paste it in my code it doesn't work :( But it does on the example you have just wrote! :o

Comment: Make sure you also add the id on the form element and remove the onclick attribute from the input.